# Changing default pagination in Yii to 50

Tags: php, yii, pagination

Working with yii framework and was wondering if there was a way of changing the default pagination.  Currently it's at 10 elements, and I would like to make it 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set pagination by

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('model name',
    array('pagination' => array(
          'pageSize' => 50,
        ),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

CPagination->$pageSize Number of items in each page. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CPagination#pageSize-detail

In yii/framework/web/CPagination.php, change

```
const DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE=20;
/**
 * @var string name of the GET variable storing the current page index. Defaults to 'page'.
 */
```

to

```
const DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE=50;
/**
 * @var string name of the GET variable storing the current page index. Defaults to 'page'.
 */
```

This will adjust the page, and pagination accordingly.

Comment: You should not change the frameworks code itself. It would break if you do an update, rendering your app to an unconditional state.